# Is it possible to import ovf directly from datastore?

Tags: vsphere, pyvmomi

I am looking for the solution to deploy ovf directly from the datastore rather than local directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not something that is currently supported. If you're on a newer release of vCenter, you may be able to use the Content Library to stage the OVF on a local datastore.